# Speed up converting CSV to HDF5 in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking for a way to speed up this process.  I have it functioning, but it is going to take days to complete.
I have a data file for each day of a year.  And, I want to combine them into a single HDF5 file with a node for each data label (data tag).
The data looks like this:

```
a,1468004920,986.078
a,1468004921,986.078
a,1468004922,987.078
a,1468004923,986.178
a,1468004924,984.078
b,1468004920,986.078
b,1468004924,986.078
b,1468004928,987.078
c,1468004924,98.608
c,1468004928,97.078
c,1468004932,98.078
```

Note that there are different numbers of entries, and different update frequencies for each data tag.  Each actual data file has about 4 million rows, and about 4000 different tag labels, in each single day file, and then I have a year of data.
The following code does what I want.  But running it for every file will take days to complete.  I'm looking for suggestions to speed this up:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import pytz
MI = pytz.timezone('US/Central')

def readFile(file_name):
    tmp_data=pd.read_csv(file_name,index_col=[1],names=['Tag','Timestamp','Value'])
    tmp_data.index=pd.to_datetime(tmp_data.index,unit='s')
    tmp_data.index.tz=MI
    tmp_data['Tag']=tmp_data['Tag'].astype('category')
    tag_names=tmp_data.Tag.unique()
    for idx,name in enumerate(tag_names):
        tmp_data.loc[tmp_data.Tag==name].Value.to_hdf('test.h5',name,complevel=9, complib='blosc',format='table',append=True)

for name in ['test1.csv']:
    readFile(name)
```

Essentially, what I'm trying to do is to "unwrap" the CSV data, so each tag is separate in the HDF5 file.  So, I want to get all the data tagged "a" into a single leaf of an hdf5 file for a year, and all the "b" data into the next leaf etc.  So, I need to run the above code on each of 365 files.  I did try with and without compression and I also tried index=False.  But, neither seemed to have a large effect.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way:

```
MI = pytz.timezone('US/Central')

tmp_data=pd.read_csv('test1.txt',index_col=[1],names=['Tag','Timestamp','Value'])
tmp_data.index=pd.to_datetime(tmp_data.index,unit='s')
tmp_data.index.tz=MI

hdf_key = 'my_key'

store = pd.HDFStore('/path/to/file.h5')

for loop which processes all your CSV files:
    # pay attention at index=False - we want to index everything at the end
    store.append(hdf_key, tmp_data, complevel=9, complib='blosc', append=True, index=False)

# all CSV files have been processed, let's index everything...
store.create_table_index(hdf_key, columns=['Tag','Value'], optlevel=9, kind='full')
```

Comment: I think that what you are suggesting is to use index=False.  Which I have tried without much change.  But, your code removes the important part from the loop.  tmp_data is my csv data, and for each file, in my actual code "test.txt" is actually a variable where I put the filename.  So, I then put each tag into a different node.  Your code puts the whole file into a single node.

Comment: To clarify, I just edited my code, to use a function.  The issue is how to get  readFile to be faster.